# State not being updated in another component react/nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm facing a issue

I'm creating a cart and In my main _app.js file while you can call as a index.js file of react has a usestate hook

I'm passing the function to update the var in one component and I'm passing the var itself in other component, the var is being properly updated but the other component where i sent the state var to doesn't update the new data until we don't refresh the page

```
const UserContext = createContext()
const [amount,setAmount] = useState(0)
<UserContext.Provider value={{amount,setAmount}}>
<Navbar/>
<Cart/>
</UserContext>
```

In the cart there is something like this

```
const {UserContext} from './_app.js'
const {setAmount} = useContext(UserContext)
<button onClick={()=>setAmount(50)}></button>
```

In navbar there is this

```
const {UserContext} from './_app.js'
const {amount} = useContext(UserContext)
<span>{amount}</span>
```

//returns 0 even after update in cart component

please help!

Comment: Add the code to be able to help you. Your question is too general too be answered in the current conditions

Comment: Please read this and correct your question regarding those rules:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Freestyle09 I did changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where is `const UserContext = createContext()` being declared? Please show us the full code and not just parts of it.

Comment: @juliomalves i rewrote my whole code and it worked. I think i had messed up something so the state wasn't being updated thanks for anything everyone

Answer (score 2):

When passing props, the prop should match the name that you are trying to use, instead of specifying the prop actually named `props`:

```js
const [amount,setAmount] = useState(0)

<Navbar amount={amount}/>
<Cart setAmount={setAmount}/>
```

Then within those components you should have access to `props.amount` or `props.setAmount`

Comment: Actually I'm using context api, so Props isn't a problem. the setamount function is working fine. but the Navbar doesn't seem to rerender the amount data even after the value has been changed in main component

Comment: @EldernyBruh Maybe set up a codesandbox that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-oskar-3tvwme

I'm just getting crazy here the amount is being updated but in my code not -_0

Answer (score -1):

You should save your `amount` state as a context instead.
Meaning, instead of putting `{amount, setAmount}` in your context, just save the `amount` in there and whenever you want to make changes to it, just use the proper context mechanisms to do so.
Just look at React context documentation for examples.